# How can I create form using this django model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, web-deployment

I am trying to create **form** using this **model**. I want to add data in this database **model** using **form** to perform CRUD operation. I am using MySQL database.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from .managers import CategoryManager, SubCategoryManager


# this is my parent model 
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='children',
        null=True,
        blank=True

    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Nodes'


class Category(Node):
    object = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


class SubCategory(Node):
    object = SubCategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = 'SubCategories'


class Product(models.Model):
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Imagine smart compiler](https://www.imagine.ai) which allows automatic generating of code + tests for your CRUD APIs and Django models from a very simple config. Amongst other things, it generates code in the correct way to handle foreign key relationships in Django Views. You can also try a demo here [imagine.ai/demo](https://www.imagine.ai)

PS: Something like this simple config will generate all the code for the CRUD API along with the tests!

```
Model Node {
    id integer [primary-key]
    name string [max-length 150]
}

Model Product {
    id integer [primary-key]
    name string [max-length 100]
    description string [nullable]
}
```